# NavigationLink, but navigate manually without specifying a View

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am wondering if there is a possibility to use `NavigationLink` in a way that I can execute some logic and conditionally navigate. If user presses a `NavigationLink` and the item that is pressed is already open in a different tab, I want to navigate to that tab instead of opening a view.

Ofcourse I can create my own view and add a Chevron to it, but `NavigationLink` also has an animation which I want to keep.

Usecase: I have a chat application where the same chat item can appear in multiple lists in different tabs. If the user has chat A open in tab A, it could be that chat A is also in a list in tab B. If the user tabs on that chat on tab B, the app should switch to tab A and do nothing on tab B.

Comment: You say that you want to keep the `NavigationLink` in order to have its animation, but in case you just need to change TAB, you don't need that animation, right? You just need to change TAB.

Comment: @superpuccio what do you mean with TAB? I want to keep using SwiftUI native components and don't want to re-invent the wheel. Maybe somebody has a clever solution.

Comment: In your question you said that: "If the user taps on that chat on ->tab<- B, the app should switch to ->tab<- A and do nothing on ->tab<- B." :) I mean, you've used the term tab in your question. So, I'm asking: if you have to switch between tab A and tab B, there's no animation involved. So, in that case a `NavigationLink` is not needed. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: @superpuccio a ok because you typed it capitalized, I thought it was an abbreviation. Yes I do not need an animation if the tab is already open, but I want to lazy calculate the next screen/tab if the user pressed the `NavigationLink`.